# Passing pointers to function in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, doubly-linked-list

Could someone please tell me why are pointers `head` and `tail` different when exiting function `reverse`?

```
struct elem{
    int val;
    elem* prev;
    elem* next;
    ...
};
void print(elem* head,elem* tail){...}
void insertAtEnd(elem* e,elem* tail){...}
void reverse(elem* head,elem* tail){
    elem* headref = head;
    elem* temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL){
        elem* t = temp->prev;
        temp->prev = temp->next;
        temp->next = t;
        temp = temp->prev;
    }
    head = tail;
    tail = headref;
    print(head,tail);
}
int main(){
    elem* head = new elem();
    elem* tail = new elem();
    ...
    print(head,tail);
    reverse(head,tail);
    print(head,tail);
    return 0;
}
```

`print()` inside function `reverse` works fine. Next `print` (just before `return 0` in `main`) causes segmentation fault (`head->next` points to `NULL`).

Comment: Add print method code

Comment: Print function causes issues and you don't include the code inside Print().

Comment: Why? For the same reason that `void f(int x) { x = 3;} int main() { int a = 0; f(a); std::cout << a; }` prints `0`, not `3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `void reverse(elem* head,elem* tail)`, you don't modify pointer (you may modify content).

You probably mean

```
void reverse(elem*& head, elem*& tail)
```

to modify `head` and `tail`.

Answer (score 2):

The pointers in `main()` themselves don't change after calling `reverse()`, because you pass them to `reverse()` by value, and the code in the function only modifies its own copies *of the pointers*. However, *the contents of the `elem` objects* they point to have been changed by the `reverse()` function.

That is, `head` in `main()` still points to the same `elem` object it used to point to before, but now that `elem` object is the tail of the list (because you changed its contents in the `reverse()` function and now its `next` member is `nullptr`). Similarly, `tail` in `main()` points to an `elem` that is now the head of the list.

Answer (score 2):

Calling reverse doesn't change head and tail because they are passed by value (reverse only modifies its private copies). If you change the declaration of reverse to

```
void reverse(elem *&head, elem *&tail)
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Without analysing your code in detail, When you are reversing you are passing pointers to your elements, so the one called head is now the tail and the one called tail is now the head.

So after you will need to `print( tail, head )`

Your `print` function obviously does not check for `null` that is, it will cause an access violation if `next` is nullptr before it reaches your `tail`. And it will be because `head` is the tail so its `next` will indeed be nullptr.

If you actually want the `reverse` function to change the pointers themselves as well as what they point to, so you get a reversed list with the names `head` and `tail` swapped, pass them by reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your exchange of pointers inside reverse() is local. It will be discarded once you leave the function scope. To achieve the exchange, yo0u have to use double pointers:

```
void reverse(elem** head, elem** tail){
    elem* headref = *head;
    elem* temp = *head;
    while(temp != NULL){
        elem* t = temp->prev;
        temp->prev = temp->next;
        temp->next = t;
        temp = temp->prev;
    }
    *head = *tail;
    *tail = headref;
    print(*head,*tail);
}
```

And pass addresses of head and tail:

```
reverse(&head, &tail);
```

P.S. Sorry for possible bugs - I didn't test the code